# Connect to page with table Confluence with Python

Tags: python-2.7, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have started a server using [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) on Centos and have created one page with a table.

Now I want to connect to my page then parse html there and find row&columns but I cannot connect to the page.

My page is located on: http://localhost:8090/display/TEST/Confluence

How can I connect to my page and parse the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a confluenca api to get the page ID

```
from atlassian import Confluence
space = '~MYSPACE'
title_parent = 'PARENT_PAGE_ID'
p_id = confluence.get_page_id(space, title_parent)
print(p_id)

title = 'New page'
body = 'This is the body of a new page'
status = confluence.create_page(space, title, body, parent_id=p_id, type='page', 
                                representation='storage')
print(status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Atlassian Example [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples). For updating your page, you need to know your page ID.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to make two request. The first will be a search that will return you the ID of the page, while the latter will return for its contents.

1. Search

```python
    import requests
    url = confluence_host + '/rest/api/content/'
    res = requests.get(url=url + 'search',
                       params={'cql': 'space="TEST" AND title="Page Titile'})
    page_id = res.json()['results'][0]['id']
```

2. Get HTML

```python
    import requests
    url = confluence_host + '/rest/api/content/'
    page = requests.get(url=url + page_id,
                        params={'expand': 'body.storage'}).json()
    html = page['body']['storage']['value']
```